# Can session.save method in hibernate be used for updating the entity

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate, if we use session.save method instead of session.update for updating an entity.what will the behavior be like.I was asked this question by a colleague of mine and was totally short of answers.

Comment: The javadoc is clear: "persists the given **transient** instance". So why would you use it to update and persistent instance?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggest that `save` will assign an id to your entity (Or use the current id if present) and try to `insert` it in the Database.

Therefore, if you have constraints of uniqueness on your table, you will end up with an Hibernate Exception.

If not, you will have twice the entry.

(I think)